# How can I zoom into a picture and have it disappear using ng-click?

Tags: html, angularjs, css, frontend

I want to click a button and have the background image zoom in and then disappear;

Right now I have the image disappearing when the button is clicked, but I cannot get the background image to disappear **after** the zooming in has occurred.

Comment: Please post what you tried so far. There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with [hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover)

and [visibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility)

Here the code:

```css
img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  -webkit-transition: all 6s;
  -o-transition: all 6s;
  transition: all 6s;
}
img:hover {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<img src="http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/seccov/images/2/23/Firefox-512-300x300.png/revision/latest?cb=20110314020706" alt="firefox" class="img">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I want to click a button, that is over the image, and then have that zoom into the picture and have it disappear